# React vite typescript error when importing an svg - Cannot find module .svg?react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I have followed instructions on how to use [vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr). I have installed it and added a declaration helper for type inference to `vite-env.d.ts`:

```
// / <reference types="vite/client" />
// / <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

I have an svg file inside an assets folder that I import like this to my component:

```
import Logo from '../assets/mountain.svg?react'
```

But, I get typescript error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '../assets/mountain.svg?react' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

How can I avoid this error?

I have also tried to declare an svg type as ReactComponent:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react'

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
  >
}
```

And then import an svg like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../assets/mountain.svg'
```

But, then I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/assets/mountain.svg?import' does not provide an export named 'ReactComponent'
```

Comment: is it available if you hover on it. if it is i guess try maybe adding the path shortcut in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it's still useful

```
// / <reference types="vite/client" />
// / <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

should be

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

I had the same problem which was fixed this way.